# How to fix sizing issue on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

Here's an example of what I'm talking about:

[image]

As you can see, the scroll bar is cut off, and there's a text box in the middle that is just completely covered up. The program text isn't blurry, and other programs are working fine. I've tried changing the compatibility mode to Win 8 and Win 7, with no avail. My DPI is on 150% "Recommended" in Windows Settings. What is the fix to this?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem myself. First, I went into settings and changed the resolution to the highest resolution where it would display properly. For me, it was 1600 x 900.

I signed out, signed back in, and then changed it back to the standard 1920 x 1080. Now the program works as normal.